# Como eu retiro os caracteres das variáveis no PHP para mandar para o banco?

Tags: php

Como eu retiro os caracteres ".", "-", "/", "(" e ")" das variáveis no PHP para mandar para o banco de dados?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("_cabecalho.php");
    include("_bUsuario.php");

    $btnCad = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnCad', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    if ($btnCad) {

        $nome = $_POST['nome'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
        $cpfBd = explode('.', $cpf);
        $cpfBd = explode('-', $cpfBd);
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $senha1 = $_POST['senha1'];
        $senha = password_hash($senha1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $celular = $_POST['celular'];
        $celularBd = explode('(', $celular);
        $celularBd = explode(')', $celularBd);
        $celularBd = explode('-', $celularBd);
        $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
        $telefoneBd = explode('(', $telefone);
        $telefoneBd = explode(')', $telefoneBd);
        $telefoneBd = explode('-', $telefoneBd);
        $data = $_POST['dtn'];
        $dataBd = explode('/', $data);
        $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
        $cep = $_POST['cep'];
        $cepBd = explode('-', $cep);
        $rua = $_POST['rua'];
        $numero = $_POST['numero'];
        $bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
        $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
        $estado = $_POST['uf'];

        if (insereUsuario($conexao, $nome, $email, $login, $senha, $celularBd, $telefoneBd, $sexo, $cepBd, $rua, $numero, $bairro, $cidade, $estado, $cpfBd, $dataBd)) {
            ?>
            <p class="center green-text">O Usuario <?= $login ?> foi adicionado.</p>
            <?php 
        } 
        else {
            $msg = mysqli_error($conexao);
            ?>
            <p class="center red-text">O Usuario <?= $login ?> não foi adicionado: <?= $msg ?></p>
            <?php
        }

<?php
    include("conecta.php");

    function insereUsuario($conexao, $nome, $email, $login, $senha, $celularBd, $telefoneBd, $sexo, $cepBd, $rua, $numero, $bairro, $cidade, $estado, $cpfBd, $dataBd) {
        $query = "insert into usuarios (nome, email, login, senha, celular, telefone, sexo, cep, rua, numero, bairro, cidade, estado, cpf, datanascimento) 
                 values ('{$nome}', '{$email}', '{$login}', '{$senha}', {$celularBd},   {$telefoneBd}, '{$sexo}', {$cepBd}, '{$rua}', {$numero}, '{$bairro}', '{$cidade}', '{$estado}', {$cpfBd}, {$dataBd})";
        return mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
    }
```

E esta dando esse erro aqui no navegador [image: erro pagina do navegador]

Comment: Olá amigo. Você não deve anexar imagens do código. Isso está claro nas regras da comunidade. Sugiro que você edite sua resposta e anexa o código digitado quanto antes ou será negativado pelo os demais usuários. Abraços!

Comment: Editei a primeira imagem para código, por favor, faça o mesmo na segunda imagem.

Comment: Desculpa eu não sabia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 - A função `explode()` não serve para remover caracteres, a sua função é de explodir um string separando seu valor em uma array de acordo com o parametro escolhido, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
$string = 'a|b|c|d';
$arr = explode('|',$string);
//O exemplo retorna
$arr[0] = 'a';
$arr[1] = 'b';
$arr[2] = 'c';
$arr[3] = 'd';
```

2 - Para remover caracteres especiais de uma string, como no seu caso, que você precisa remover `'.'` e `'-'` use a função `str_replace()`, como no exemplo a seguir:

```
$cepBd = str_replace("-", "", $cep);
```

A função `str_replace()` significa:

```
str_replace('caractere a ser substituido','caractere que vai substituir (pode ser vazio)', 'string que deverá ser alterada')
```

PS:
Existe mais de uma função com resultado parecido com suas particularidades e modo de uso, segue a baixo para consulta:

[str_ireplace();](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-ireplace.php)

[strstr();](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtr.php)

[substr_replace();](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr-replace.php)

[preg_replace();](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 0):

O `explode()` pede 3 parametros o terceiro que eatá faltando é a quantidade máxima de elementos no array, lembrando que o explode gera um array. No seu caso acredito que o que precisa é o 0 no caso 1 elemento por exemplo:

```
$str = explode('/', $_POST['str'], 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

- Substituição de strings é uma operação muito comum, mas nem sempre feita de forma adequada.
- A função mais simples é `str_replace` que serve para substituir todas ocorrências de uma sequência de caracteres por outra, dentro de uma string.
- Quando se quer substituir várias sequências de caracteres por outras de uma só vez, pode ser mais útil utilizar a função passando dois arrays (um com as sequências a serem buscadas e outro com as sequências usadas para substituir).

Exemplo:

```
$str = '(21)1234-5678';
$substituirIsso = array('-', ')', '(');
$porIsso = array('');
$resultado = str_replace($substituirIsso, $porIsso, $str);
```

[**resultado - ideone**](https://ideone.com/zof43O)

> A vantagem de se utilizar o array ao invés de chamar `str_replace` duas ou mais vezes é que a string só precisa ser percorrida uma única vez.

**No seu caso ficaria assim:**

[**Exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/vkXv9a)

```
function removeCaracteres($str){
    return str_replace(array(".", "-", "/", "(", ")"), "", $str);
}

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $cpfBd = removeCaracteres($cpf);

    $login = $_POST['login'];
    $senha1 = $_POST['senha1'];
    $senha = password_hash($senha1, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $celular = $_POST['celular'];
    $celularBd = removeCaracteres($celular);

    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $telefoneBd = removeCaracteres($telefone);

    $data = $_POST['dtn'];
    $dataBd = removeCaracteres($data);

    $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];

    $cep = $_POST['cep'];
    $cepBd = removeCaracteres($cep);

    $rua = $_POST['rua'];
    $numero = $_POST['numero'];
    $bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
    $estado = $_POST['uf'];
```